# How to put parameters in URL using Java and httpclient?

Tags: java, httpclient, rest

I am really new to Http stuffs and am trying to put parameters in the URL in order to make some requests from a certain API.

For example, the guide for the API says that we need to do

```
https POST api_site.io/users/$username/token,
```

but using Java, how do we pass the username parameter before /token and do a request for POST?

This is the start and I have a lot more things to do for the next but if someone enlightens the way of how to start, I think can do the other things by myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/, please refer this link. It has some useful examples to get you started

Comment: @pratap thank you for your comment, but how do we get an user input for the paramenter "username" and put it in between /users/ and /token?

Comment: there are multiple ways, if its web application, you can get the username from session of logged in user. If its just a simple java client, you can read the username from the properties file or provide it as argument while running the class. Once you get the username, you would need to replace that in the above URI.